# Highlight link under hidden input on hover

Tags: html, css

I have the following markup:

```
<li class="menu-option">
    <a class="menu-option-link">File</a>
    <input class="menu-option-upload-input" type="file">
</li>
```

An the following styles:

```
.menu-option {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #c7d0d9;
}

.menu-option-link {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    color: #000000;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding-left: 8px;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 36px;
}

.menu-option-link:hover {
   background: green;   
}

.menu-option-upload-input {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

So basically the input is hidden but occupies the entire width and height of the   `li.menu-option`. When hovered over `a.menu-option-link` I want it hovered, but when clicked I want to trigger action specific to `input`. Is that possible?

Comment: Ignore the black box on the fiddle. That's irrelevant.

Comment: So you want to display the input while file link is hovered?

Comment: No, I want to highlight the link and don't want a user to see input.

Comment: So why your question's title is "Highlight hidden input on hover"?! I wonder why...

Comment: @John, edited the title

Comment: The absolute position doesn't let you see the hover.

Comment: Can you explain "Highlight link"? What is under hidden input?

Comment: @ManojKumar I want for the user to think he clicks on the simple link, but instead of handling this link, I want to trigger default browser behavior of showing file selection dialog

Comment: So you want to highlight the `file` text on click, not `:hover`? Confused again.

Comment: @ManojKumar, no, highlight on hover

Comment: Then you are looking for CodeRomeos solution. Isn't it?

Comment: @Maximus Are you looking for something like this? [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/vivekkupadhyay/4rn323wz/2)

Comment: @vivekkupadhyay, yeah, kind of. In your example I need the button to be highlighted when hovered.

Comment: @ManojKumar, yeah, but he's just highlighting `li` instead of `a`. I certainly can do that, but I'm wondering whether there is any way to highlight `a` and not change the entire approach

Comment: @Maximus can you change your *structure* ? If yes then `<a class="menu-option-link">File<input class="menu-option-upload-input" type="file"></a>` will do the trick for you.

Comment: @vivekkupadhyay, interestingly, I've tried this before, it works in the fiddler, but not in my app. Will try to figure out why. Thanks

Comment: @Maximus May be coz of your *CSS*. First you've to set `position: relative` for your `.menu-option-link` and then set `left: 0` for your `.menu-option-upload-input`, try using this.

Comment: @vivekkupadhyay, thanks, but it's something different

Answer (score 0):

You may try this.

```css
.menu-option {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #c7d0d9;
}
.menu-option:hover .menu-option-link{color:red;background:#ddd}
.menu-option-link {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    color: #000000;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding-left: 8px;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 36px;
}

.menu-option-upload-input {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="someBox"></div>
<ul>
    <li class="menu-option">
        <a class="menu-option-link">File</a>
        <input class="menu-option-upload-input" type="file">
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Note that this won't work on IE. I think for a better cross browser compatibility should use jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Hi because you used to `absolute` `position` and define `z-index` is `1` now define your 
`.menu-option-link` **class** `position` `relative`  and `z-index` `2`

as like  this

```css
.menu-option {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #c7d0d9;
}

.menu-option-link {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    color: #000000;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding-left: 8px;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 36px;
  position:relative;
  z-index:2;
}

.menu-option-link:hover {
   background: green;   
}

.menu-option-upload-input {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<li class="menu-option">
    <a class="menu-option-link">File</a>
    <input class="menu-option-upload-input" type="file">
</li>
```

Comment: The file selection dialog is not open by browser when clicked on the link